# Kinetic energy and acceleration of two bodies (easy)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, acceleration, velocity

I am really confused by this and I am not sure what assumption I have made that is wrong.
KE $ = \frac{1}{2}m v^2 $.
Consider a system of a BOX and a BALL and they both have a mass of $2  kg$ each:

1. Accelerating them both from rest to $2 m/s$ velocity will require
   $\mathrm{KE} =8J$
2. Accelerating the ball an additional $3 m/s$ so it travels at $5m/s$ will
   require an extra $+9J$
3. Therefore, considering the velocity of the two objects in this
   the system, the total KE $= 29J$

BUT, we only put in 17J

Why is this the case?

p.s. neglect drag and friction effects

Comment: Don't change reference frames in the middle of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The second part accelerating the ball from $2 m/s$ to $5 m/s$ requires:
$$
   \frac{1}{2}\times 2 \times 5^2 - \frac{1}{2}\times 2\times 2^2 = 25 -4 = 21 (J).
$$

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you mistyped this. As @ytlu pointed out.  For the first part it is 8J but for second part it is from 2 m/s to 5 m/s which gives 21 J. Adding both K.E gives 29J

Hope this helps